# Query to select from two different tables

Tags: sql

I would like to select from two tables and display my result using this query:

```
CREATE TABLE Buy_Table 
(
 buy_id int identity primary key, 
 user_id int, 
 amount decimal (18,2)
);
go
INSERT INTO Buy_Table 
(user_id, amount)
VALUES
('1', 10),
('1', 8),
('1', 20),
('3', 1),
 ('2', 2);
go
CREATE TABLE Sell_Table 
(
 sell_id int identity primary key, 
 user_id int, 
 amount decimal (18,2)
);
 go
 INSERT INTO Sell_Table 
 (user_id, amount)
 VALUES
 ('1', 10),
 ('1', 8),
 ('1', 20),
 ('3', 3),
 ('2', 3);
 go

select 
[user_id],
'Buy' as [Type],
buy_id as [ID],
amount

from Buy_Table

union all

select
[user_id],
'Sell',
sell_id,
amount
 from Sell_Table

order by
[user_id],
 [ID],
[Type]
```

However the above query will return each row of the user_id like this

[image]

I want to display my result to something like this in a grid:

[image]

Can this be done in query itself rather manipulating the grid? Thx

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be done in a query. No, you do not want to do it. The result sets from SQL queries are generally thought of as tables. They can be used in queries; they have rows and columns.

Doing what you want to do violates some principles of "table-ness" in a relational database. The most important is that the order of the rows is now important. In relational databases, tables represent unordered sets. Without an ordering, you don't know where the second and subsequent rows belong. Having to "borrow" information from another row seems like a bad practice, because it is. Another problem is that the first column has an ambiguous meaning now, depending on whether a row has a value there or not.

So, this is best done in the application layer because the purpose is -- presumably -- to meet some desired output standard. It *is* an interesting exercise to get this format in SQL, although the best way to do it varies by database. That said, being an interesting exercise doesn't make this a good idea.